# Pocketmine-mp problem for mcpe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I have a question.... So I made a server using PocketMine-MP, but I don't know how to port forward it for everyone and anyone to use it. I tried inputting the gateway (router ) in google, (my router is Dlink, DSL-2750B) then I logged in. I used port forwarding, placed the name as Pocketmine, the ip address as 102.168.1.18, then I places 19132 for the starting port and ending port. I then did Whatsmyip.org, then I went into Minecraft pe and placed my ip and port in the external section then I tried the server. it just says "Could not connect to Server". I tried several times but it still didn't work..... Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: I don't know much about servers, but it might that your server's IP isn't static, i.e. It can change. (This MAY be the case if the server is hosted on a computer.

Comment: So does my dvice need to be static or not?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My ip address is actually 192.168.1.18 not 102.168.1.18

Comment: I think it should be your original IP 192.168.1.18 not from the whatsmyip

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/) that lets you host things on one IP if you have a dynamic IP Address. That gives you a static URL that you can use to connect to. It should update the IP address every hour or so so that you can keep using the same IP.